# jvisualvm -how to see live objects with memory consumption

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I am trying to use JVisualVM to see my applications live objects and their corresponding memory count (probably at the package level)

How do I achieve the same when I connect using a jstad connection

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure you cannot do that with VisualVM against a running process. What you need to do is to take a heap dump using [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) (e.g. jmap -dump:format=b,file=heapdump.bin) and then use a tool like [mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyze that dump.

Be aware that the heap dump will block your process for considerable time, especially if you have a large heap.

What you also can do to get information on a more general level is to run jmap -histo:live against your process to see just the number of objects of each type and their footprints.

Comment: jmap is great, thanks for the tip. I just used it to get a list of live objects for a heap of size 17GB and it took about 3 seconds. for my purposes getting a number of instances for each class is sufficient to identify memory bloats.

Answer (score 5):

VisualVM absolutely supports viewing and inspecting live objects via a Heap Dump, as well as live sampled allocations.

For the heap dump right click the process, select Heap Dump.

This opens the Heap Dump view. On the Summary page you can calculate the n biggest objects by retained size, then click through to various views.

It provides essentially the same functionality as using jmap and mat as suggested above, but with vastly nicer workflow and usability.